# ENOSPC - Writing multiple times a file that was deleted

Tags: java, android, linux, file

i'm writing down a new Android app but I'm having some trouble.

Here's the thing: I need to fill my local storage, but when I do this, the system shows a popup saying that there's no space left to write. That's ok!

After this step, the App deletes this file and needs to rewrite again to fill the space, but I receive the error ENOSPC in the logcat even though I previously deleted the file.

Is there a way, or a method to call to let the system update their references in order to let me write inside the local storage because the disk space is not full, but it only needs to be updated?

In other words..

1. Filling the space - meanwhile got the Android popup saying no empty space left
2. Deleting the file - the popup still stays there
3. Filling again the space - got an error of ENOSPC in my logcat even though the file has been deleted and there's new space to fill

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using a low-level programming language (NDK library and C++)